# How do you correctly detect escape characters in a JSON object in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, regex

I need to detect escape characters in an API call. 
I've written a function below that takes in a specific value and validates whether it contains escape characters using a regular expression.

Function:

```
var checkEscapeChars = function (value){
var containsEscapeChars = /\\[ubfnrtv0'"\\]/g.test(value);
return containsEscapeChars; // returns true when contains escape chars
};
```

My understanding is that if the value is '\f' (line feed), then the function should return true - but it doesn't it returns false. I believe this is because the regex tester treats '\f' and interpreted '\f' differently.

How would I detect escape characters? (I'm running in Node 4.4.7 (and I can't update)).

Thanks

Edit: 
I've built an API and cannot accept escape characters as they cannot be written to my database. I cannot make any other changes to the system, and have to correctly evaluate whether a string contains escape characters.

I'm inputting '\f', which translates to a line feed escape character. The function should therefore return: true (the string contains an escape character), but it doesn't. It returns false.

Comment: "I need to detect escape characters in an API call." — Why?

Comment: "I've written a function below that takes in a specific value" — What value? Code is all very well, but it is hard to understand the question without same input, actual output and expected output for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must build your regex this way :

`/[\b\f\n\r\t\v\0]/`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xT9qWz/2)

Your regex match `\u`, `\b`, `\f`, ... but literally

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xT9qWz/1)

> **Additional note**
>   \u is not an escape character. Here is a list :
>
> \b: backspace (U+0008 BACKSPACE)
>   \f: form feed (U+000C FORM FEED)
>   \n: line feed (U+000A LINE FEED)
>   \r: carriage return (U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN)
>   \t: horizontal tab (U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION)
>   \v: vertical tab (U+000B LINE TABULATION)
>   \0: null character (U+0000 NULL)

Comment: Thanks very much!